# Add mousewheel scrolling to AngularJS list directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a circular list in Angular, the basics of the directive are below and a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5ocXCoj6pmTxcOxru6C?p=preview). Essentially just a simple list that rotates around in either direction.

I would like to add the ability to rotate the list based on mouse scrolling but I am unsure how to implement this in Angular (without JQuery), I tried but cannot even get a response from a mousewheel event on the element using something similar to `angular.element(element).bind('scroll', function () {...});`

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

```
directives.directive('cl', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: 'true',
    transclude: 'true',
    templateUrl: 'templates/clist.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var lelems, lelem;

        scope.up = function () {
            lelems = element.find('li');
            lelem = angular.element(lelems[0]).remove();
            lelems.parent().append(lelem.clone());
        }

        scope.down = function () {
            lelems = element.find('li');
            lelem = angular.element(lelems[lelems.length - 1]).remove();
            lelems.parent().prepend(lelem.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/maxmalik/VmMf2/2/
Used Hamster library to track mouse wheel.

Comment: Thanks Max, that works but doesn't override the default window scrolling such that the list will only scroll up when the window cannot scroll up anymore and vice versa. I need to prevent the default when scrolling that particular element, any thoughts?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VmMf2/3/ 
Updated. Just used event.preventDefault() method

Comment: Tried that but it prevented all window scrolling. Instead of using Hamster I have updated my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5ocXCoj6pmTxcOxru6C?p=preview) which seems to work well. My only concern is how browser compatible it is after seeing how complex (beyond my level of comprehension anyway) Hamster is.

Comment: Mouse wheel observer is linked to div control that is produced by the "cl" directive. Div control is stretched on window width. That's why you think that it prevented all window scrolling.
Hamster is just useful wrapper over DOM.